# If $\sum_{i=1}^{n} n a_n$ converge ,does $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $ a_n \geq 0 $, then is easy to get.
Cause $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n a_n} = 0$$ , so $\sum_{i=1}^{n} n a_n$ converge, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_n$ also converge.

When $ a_n $ not always positive, does $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_n $ still converge? I guess $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} n a_n $ construct a not absolute convergence $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} n a_n $, then maybe $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_n $ will diverge. Seem not so easy.

Comment: The statement in the title is false even if $a_n \geq 0$. Perhaps you have made  a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n$ converges, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges too, by [Abel's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test):$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n(na_n),$$and the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is monotonic and its limit is $0$.

Comment: Maybe my previous question is confused. I mean if If $\sum_{i=1}^{n} n a_n$ converge ,does $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_n $ converge? Contrary to your answer

Comment: @hstk In the original version of your question, you wrote “iff”, not just “if”.

Comment: Now, I change it. I used 'iff' wrongly.

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: Oh, I forget to use Abel'ss criterion. It's easy. I’m careless.